# Unable to Install TeamViewer (Duplicate doesn't work.)

Tags: teamviewer

Downloading TeamViewer:

```
mahi@mahi-lenovo-ideapad-320-15ikb:~$ wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb
--2019-07-06 10:45:44--  https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb
Resolving download.teamviewer.com (download.teamviewer.com)... 13.75.43.250
Connecting to download.teamviewer.com (download.teamviewer.com)|13.75.43.250|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://dl.teamviewer.com/download/linux/version_14x/teamviewer_14.3.4730_amd64.deb [following]
--2019-07-06 10:45:46--  https://dl.teamviewer.com/download/linux/version_14x/teamviewer_14.3.4730_amd64.deb
Resolving dl.teamviewer.com (dl.teamviewer.com)... 104.16.63.16, 104.16.62.16, 2606:4700::6810:3f10, ...
Connecting to dl.teamviewer.com (dl.teamviewer.com)|104.16.63.16|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 13489636 (13M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘teamviewer_amd64.deb.1’

teamviewer_amd64. 100%[===========>]  12.86M  1.44MB/s    in 10s     

2019-07-06 10:45:57 (1.27 MB/s) - ‘teamviewer_amd64.deb.1’ saved [13489636/13489636]
```

Installing TeamViewer:

```
mahi@mahi-lenovo-ideapad-320-15ikb:~$ sudo apt install ./teamviewer_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for mahi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'teamviewer' instead of './teamviewer_amd64.deb'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5
  libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5
  qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts
  qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-window2
  qml-module-qtquick2
Suggested packages:
  qt5-qmltooling-plugins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5
  libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5
  qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts
  qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-window2
  qml-module-qtquick2 teamviewer
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 178 kB/29.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 135 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 /home/mahi/teamviewer_amd64.deb teamviewer amd64 14.3.4730 [13.5 MB]
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libqt5printsupport5 amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5printsupport5_5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Now with `--fix-missing`:

```
mahi@mahi-lenovo-ideapad-320-15ikb:~$ sudo apt install ./teamviewer_amd64.deb --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'teamviewer' instead of './teamviewer_amd64.deb'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5
  libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5
  qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts
  qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-window2
  qml-module-qtquick2
Suggested packages:
  qt5-qmltooling-plugins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5
  libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5
  qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts
  qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-window2
  qml-module-qtquick2 teamviewer
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 178 kB/29.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 135 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 /home/mahi/teamviewer_amd64.deb teamviewer amd64 14.3.4730 [13.5 MB]
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libqt5printsupport5 amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5printsupport5_5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
E: Aborting install.
```

Comment: Providing text of your issue (instead of a picture of text) would be more useful, we cannot copy/paste detail from a picture (as we can with text) which allow us to investigate your issue & provide solutions (as well as text is easier to read, when compared to picture of text)

Comment: what is you version and architecture type of ubuntu, this matters.

Comment: I'm working with latest  ubuntu 18.04 @tatsu

Comment: Did you try another mirror [as per duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544184/404-error-with-apt-get-update-dont-have-any-ppas)?  If yes, please [edit] your question which mirrors you've tried (especially try the main server).  Just saying "It doesn't work" does not provide us with any additional info

Comment: Please confirm that the duplicate doesn't  work through post your output error that you try

Comment: @Fabby I don't understand the technical terms you are using(like mirror), but I am including the terminal output after using  "the answer to the question"(of which you have attached the link)  (and I was talking about one other similar question that I said I tried, It had more commands and I could not find it again.(probably that was on some other platform))

Comment: @Fabby I am unable to include(it says something about some minimum condition required to include >= 8 links) the output I got after using "the similar problem you tagged", but after writing command: sudo apt-get update
I got errors full of message similar to : Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why I was unable to install it was because I was trying to install it using Institute ethernet(Which has some kind of proxy thing).

Thank You @Fabby, @tatsu and @guiverc for your constructive comments.